# MobileApp / Data Sync / Existing database

Tags: entity-framework, azure, azure-mobile-services, offline-mode

I'm working through the issues of using an offline data sync with a mobile back end, and have worked through numerous articles/documentation regarding it's use.

The scenario that I'm looking for is a bit different that the normal demo projects.  We have a Azure SQL db that we have been using for some time now, and a use case has come up to use this data in a mobile back end.

I have yet to see an article on how best practises of using an existing sql DB (EF codefirst), with offline data sync tables that need to inherit from EntityData, which adds additional fields for the sync process.

My original thought was to use the ef code first definition of the data models, and use them with Mobile App... however the requirement for EntityData doesn't work, as I'm not going to add those fields to a production system.

My question is, what is the best practise of using data from a production system, and get them syncing with mobile back ends?  I'm thinking a intermidary DB is required, but that just means that there are three databases/tables to sync - which doesn't feel right at this point in time.

Anybody know of an article that starts with an Azure DB, and the process/decisions they made to allow data sync to offline devices?

Comment: Why not simply use Azure Mobile App services?

Comment: This is what I'm talking about - but I'm looking for a use case scenario of how to sync with an existing db, created by code first.  The mobile app services requires the inheritance of EntityData which is required to sync data from the mobile client, to a database.  Looking for best practises/patterns when backend db is already defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This scenario is discussed in detail in my book - http://aka.ms/zumobook - chapter 3.